# PHP data selection for odd and even numbers

Tags: php, laravel

I have tables with ID in my database. I'm trying to make sure that one API is used for an even number, so that another API is used for an odd number.

The variable that I need to use for different numbers `protected $apiKey = '5cef0578-acbc-4523-88c8-b47634ca3ba6';`

My code:

```
class RandomOrgClient
{

    protected $url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke';
    protected $apiKey = 'MY KEY';
    protected $timeLimit = 300;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTimelimit($this->timeLimit);
    }
```

I tried to do something like:

```
class RandomOrgClient
{

    protected $url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke';

    if ($games_count %2 == 0) {
        protected $apiKey = 'KEY FOR ODD NUMBER';
    } else { 
    protected $apiKey = 'KEY FOR EVEN NUMBER';
    }
    protected $timeLimit = 300;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTimelimit($this->timeLimit);
        $games_count = DB::table('game_double')->count();

    }
```

But every time i received error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix a mistake?

**UPD:**

I made changes as suggested by 2 people, but now there is another problem. 1 time the code generated, the second time does not want, it's a blank page. Most likely due to the fact that I am use not correctly request at `$games_count variable`. As I understand it, even or odd should take from ID the table. I little changed variable to `$games_count = DB::table('game_double')->where('id')->get();`, and I get a white page in the browser, where my mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Just answering the update: Your where method call is incomplete: `$games_count = DB::table('game_double')->where('id')->get();`. You need to define what the "id" should equal.

Comment: @vanderbake yes, i make it, now all works. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move that conditional code into the constructor.

```
class RandomOrgClient
{
    protected $url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke';
    protected $apiKey;
    protected $timeLimit = 300;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTimelimit($this->timeLimit);
        $games_count = DB::table('game_double')->count();
        if ($games_count %2 == 0) 
        {
            $this->apiKey = 'KEY FOR ODD NUMBER';
        }
        else 
        { 
            $this->apiKey = 'KEY FOR EVEN NUMBER';
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put code in a class without it being in a function. Initialization, yes, but no conditions or the like. Move that all to your `__construct` function:

```
class RandomOrgClient
{
    protected $url = 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/2/invoke';
    protected $apiKey = 'KEY FOR EVEN NUMBER';
    protected $timeLimit = 300;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTimelimit($this->timeLimit);
        $games_count = DB::table('game_double')->count();
        if ($games_count %2 == 0) {
            $this->apiKey = 'KEY FOR ODD NUMBER';
        }
    }
```